Swap billing and shipping address in admin create order Magento 2.4
I want to swap billing and shipping address position. And also we have a checkbox on shipping address says "Same As Billing address".
I want that checkbox on billing address says "Same As Shipping Address". And the functionality that is in shipping address should work on billing address.
How I can do that in Magento 2.4?
If need more clarity please let me know. I need urgent help on this, Please!

For this to work without issue, it will require to generate a module that intercepts all the places where the logic of the shipping/billing address "same as" happens to switch that, together with a theme for the backend and frontend to make the required adjustments on location on the theme.

If you don't have external systems integrated
As you don't want to change the functionality on Magento, the quick and dirty way to handle this should be to modify the translation files for English and replace all the shipping => billing and vice versa on all the modules (backend included)
You can create the files under app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/i18n/en_US.csv (replacing Vendor and Module for the correct naming from vendor directory), or generate the translations files with magento i18n:collect-phrases --output="app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/i18n/en_US.csv" app/code/[Vendor]/[Module] to extract the located string and replace the wording.
Remember to do the static-content deploy (magento setup:static-content:deploy -f) to apply the translations.
Also, check your emails templates to make sure they work as expected.

I want to do it with overriding default functionality... @Serfe
